limit of complex function/sequence
How do I prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt \pi})^n = 0?$$
I tried writing $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt \pi})^n = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1+i)^n}{(\sqrt \pi)^n}.$$
Then $$\frac{1}{(\sqrt \pi)^n} \to 0.$$
And now what?

$|z|<1$ implies $z^{n} \to 0$. [By definition of limit, $z^{n}\to 0$ and $|z|^{n} \to 0$ are equivalent].

This question is similar to: Silly question about complex numbers - if its modulus is < 1, does raising it to higher exponents make it decrease to the real number 0?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please note that:
$$\left|\frac{1+i}{\sqrt \pi}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}<1,$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt \pi}\right)^n=0\iff
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1+i}{\sqrt \pi}\right|^n = 0$$
